# RxAndroid: when to use bindActivity and why?

Tags: android, rx-java

Is it really necessary to use `AndroidObservable.bindActivity(...)` in cases like the activity below? Since you still need to unsubscribe manually in `onDestroy` anyway.

According to [this blog](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/) post, bindActivity is necessary so:

> *you don't accidentally try to change state after it is valid to do so*

which -the way I read it- would mean there could be issues when you do certain things with the activity after `finish()` is called and thus unsubscribing in onDestroy would be too late.

**Can anyone give me an example of when unsubscribing as late as in onDestroy would actually be a problem?**

---

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/0.x/src/main/java/rx/android/observables/AndroidObservable.java) for `AndroidObservable.java` the predicate function used for bindActivity is:

```
private static final Func1<Activity, Boolean> ACTIVITY_VALIDATOR = new Func1<Activity, Boolean>() {
@Override public Boolean call(Activity activity) {
        return !activity.isFinishing();
    }
};
```

Wouldn't it be better to also check for configuration changes, like:

```
private static final Func1<Activity, Boolean> ACTIVITY_VALIDATOR = new Func1<Activity, Boolean>() {
@Override public Boolean call(Activity activity) {
        return !activity.isFinishing() && !activity.isChangingConfigurations();
    }
};
```

???

---

**SomeActivity.java**

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements Observer<String> {
    private Subscription subscription;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        subscription = getObservable().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(this);

        // or use bindActivity here????
        // subscription = AndroidObservable.bindActivity(this, getObservable()).subscribe(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        // do something with the activity state...
    }

    @Override public void onCompleted() {}
    @Override public void onError(Throwable throwable) {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do fragment transactions after `onSaveInstanceState` has been called, so if your subscribe opens a `DialogFragment` then doing that before `onDestroy` but after `onSaveInstanceState` would crash your application. This is likely to happen if the Activity is closing and a network request finishes that wants to display an error. Anything that requires saving state and so cannot be called after `onSaveInstanceState` would be a problem.

Comment: Clear answer! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you're not around anymore, but is there any reason to use DialogFragments instead of plain Dialogs? I've faceplanted against this error many many times and at this point I just gave up and went back to the deprecated ones.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM `DialogFragment` has a Fragment lifecycle instead of `Dialog` which is tied to the activity. They can easily survive rotation, unlike plain `Dialog`.

Comment: @GDanger So for applications locked to portrait, there's no difference plus you avoid fragment's lolcycles and the crash mentioned above.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM Rotation is only the easiest to see example. If instead of rotation the activity were being killed and resumed for some other reason, you likely would want your dialog to persist. 

For example, your activity could show a dialog, get backgrounded and reclaimed for memory, and then get resumed. `Dialog` would mysteriously be gone, `DialogFragment` would not.

Comment: @GDanger I'd rather lose that one on that corner case than having to deal with the lolcycle all the time.